# Splash screen not appearing on iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic4, splash-screen

I've created an Ionic 4 chat app and it's working fine on Android.  But on iOS devices, (real devices and emulator) the Splash screen doesn't appear.  The custom app icon works on iOS devices but not the custom splash screen...it still just displays the ionic generic splash screen on launch.  There aren't any error messages in XCode when running in emulator...just the following which indicates success.

2019-10-14 23:12:19.809846-0400 App Name[5851:117235] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 10.107994ms

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />



        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        
        
            <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="4000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="300" />
```

Comment: run this command :: 'ionic cordova resources --force'

Comment: To Generate Splash Screens: you have to Paste your splash.png file in root/resources folder with 2732x2732 size. and Run command `ionic cordova resources ios`

Comment: The different splash screen sizes are already in the resources folder.